# Отключить таймаут для запроса

Tags: sql-server

Есть очень большой запрос, который задействует множество таблиц. Я прописал вроде бы настройки таймаута, но все равно где то через минут 40 выдает ошибку

```
A time out occurred while waiting to optimize the query. Rerun the query.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Появление данной ошибки может быть результатом конкуренции за ресурсы, в частности память.

Проверьте что еще выполняется на сервере в момент получения данной ошибки, возможно это хранимая процедура или задание, в таком случае можно изменить расписание и проблема будет решена.

Проверьте также состояние вашей БД, возможно она давно не обслуживалась и например перестроение индексов и обнавление статистики снизят нагрузку на сервер.